# How can I integrate Google maps v2 in Android 4.0?

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

Here is my problem:

I have been doing this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
( and many more but every single one of them gives me error )

I have done everything that it need to be ( permissions, library, API code ).
The API code is done correctly !

Here are few screenshots:
- activity_main.xml
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwuSo.jpg

- AndroidManifest.xml
  [1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSKbU.jpg
  [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ClLQ.jpg

**Error:**

```
11-07 20:02:28.969: E/Godfrey5(5234): BitmapFactory.java, decodeStream()
11-07 20:02:28.969: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, nativeDecodeAsset()
11-07 20:02:28.969: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, doDecode()
11-07 20:02:28.969: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, doDecode(),filename=(null)
11-07 20:02:29.019: E/Godfrey5(5234): BitmapFactory.java, decodeStream()
11-07 20:02:29.019: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, nativeDecodeAsset()
11-07 20:02:29.019: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, doDecode()
11-07 20:02:29.019: E/BitmapFactory(5234): Godfrey5==BitmapFactory.cpp, doDecode(),filename=(null)
11-07 20:02:29.049: W/dalvikvm(5234): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d1438)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.money.irl/com.money.irl.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4777)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.money.irl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     ... 11 more
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-07 20:02:29.079: E/AndroidRuntime(5234):     ... 21 more
```

The project is compiled with Google API, the library ( google-play-services_lib ) is loaded, and there is no code added in MainActivity.java ( only the generated from the Eclipse ).

I have added Support Library from right click on the project > Android Tools > Add support library , accept and install.

When I try to start on my phone ( ZTE blade 3 pro ) the app is giving error. If I delete the "

Comment: this is almost the exact same issue as posted directly below you, they are even using the same tutorial. please search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844429/android-google-maps-v2-a-lot-of-errors

Comment: You people are life saver. I have been torturing myself for 2 days. Sorry for my ignorance but I did tried to search on google and on StackOverflow about this problem and...

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @tyczj here and many others:

Just add this above  in the AndroidManifest.xml without changing anything from this code:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />*
```